# How to get the content of current page by passing id from page link to controller

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am working in Codeigniter.
Here is my code which I have written so far to achieve what I am thinking.
**View:**

```
<li><a href=" echo $menu->url.'/'.$menu->id " >Gallery</a></li>
```

**Controller:**

```
function view($id){

$content['content'] = $this->MyModel->getContent($id);
$data['header'] = $this->load->view('header', '', true);
$data['content'] = $this->load->view('content', $content, true);
$this->load->view('main_view', $data);

}
```

**Model**

```
 function getContent($id){

$this->db->select('page_title, content');
$this->db->from('admin_pages');
$this->db->where('id', $id);
............
return $query;
}
```

**Route**

```
$route['view/(:any)'] = 'mycontroller/view/$1';
```

What I want to achieve here is, when I click the link in the "View" then it should show me another page with the content of that specific link fetched from the "admin_pages" table based on the parameter "$id" passed to it from the url.
**However when I click the link it gives me page not found error.**

Any kind of help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trial and error, I found a workaround which I want to share for future references if made.

I changed the link as:
**View**

```
<li><a href=" echo base_url().'page/'. $menu->id; " >Gallery</a></li>
```

Then in the route I changed:
**Route**

```
$route['page/(:any)'] = 'mycontroller/view/$1';
```

What this means is, whenever there in the URL is base_url/page followed by an "id" then it will be remapped or taken to the "view" method in the controller "mycontroller" and the id will be passed as a parameter to the method, which the method will recieve as $id in its definition.